# custom UIButton with skewed area in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uibutton

[image: http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/225/ladibig.png]

I want to have a button on a screen with this image. this image is transparent from its corners as you can see here.

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(xCo, yCo, kImageSizeWidth, kImageSizeHeight)];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aboveImg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

But the button tap is recognized out side image and I don't want that kind of functionality.

I mean tap must be recognized only when it is tapped within image not outside image.

How is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass that UIButton, then override its [`-pointInside:withEvent:` function](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW2) to something similar to

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
   if (point is in that rhombus)
     return YES;
   else
     return NO;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there is an option to have skewed button ?

Comment: @sugar: You could use some combination of `.transform`, but this method is much more flexible.

Comment: Yep ! Done With Transform. I am adding my answer - so, you can understand what exactly I Did.