# rhombus framed buttons objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, transform, skew

basically I am trying to edit not only the appearance of the button(thats the easy part) but the frame that detects the touch to be a rhombus rather then a square

html example:http://irwinproject.com

I've tried CGAfflineTransform however it doesn't allow me to make non rectangular objects. is there a way to skew

Im just wondering if this is possible because, if not could someone point me in a direction the only viable answer I've found is resorting to something along the lines of a spriteKit;

I found this however this implementation leaves dead spots on buttons where they overlap
[custom UIButton with skewed area in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918961/custom-uibutton-with-skewed-area-in-iphone)

is there a way to message people on here there was a gentleman who said he figured out how to transform but never posted his solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify the touch area of an oddly shaped button you could use a solution similar to [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton). I have used this particular project in the past myself for adjacent hexagon buttons and it worked perfectly. That said, you may have to modify it a bit to work with drawn shapes instead of images.

Comment: beautiful so basically with this it creates the button based off of visible png space... I haven't had the chance to mess with this but can this have an image with string on top?

Comment: With this particular solution it will work as long as the text is actually on top of the image. If they are side by side, I don't think the text will be tappable, but that shouldn't be too hard to add if that's the case.

Comment: it doesnt matter it works perfectly now i just have to spend a bit more time in gimp. again thank you I never thought I would find such a simple answer.